# Global debug and custom roms

Tags: android, debugging, global, ddms, rom

[image]

The above image has two devices, one rooted with CyanogenMod, and one stock TouchWiz Rom. The second device does not care if your APK has the debug flag set in the manifest, it shows everything (minus what proguard would remove from source). I am doing testing for information leakage through logcat. Does anyone know what the setting or difference in the ROMs are that allows global debug? Notice the debug next to the ROM version. It is a developer mode flag from what I remember, but I have no idea where this setting is located.